# Create a table with drill down capability(prefereably not Pivot Table)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long set of data, it can be grouped into general cathegories but I need to see the details as well.

I know how I can acheve this with a pivot table, but I am wondering if it is possible to get this done in some other way?

Note: I have well over 1000 rows in that table, whatever solution you proposu it should not require a lot of time for each row in the table.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found it in the "Data" Ribbon, there is section "Outline", it has a "Subtotal" button, select the table, and then click on "Subtotal", menu that pops ups will help you build in the "drill" capability to the table.

Comment: If it needs to be fast and painless this is the best solution after Pivot Tables which the OP doesn't want!

Answer (score 0):

Excel powerview has this functionality, available in v2013.